# Create server using 'app' as request handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

In simple NodeJS, we can create server using -

```
http.createServer(function(req,res) { /* header etc. */});
```

but I started using express and server is created automatically.
Then I proceeded to learning sockets, but socket.io required an http server to be passed as parameter to create a socket connection. So now to create the server I used -

```
http.createServer(app);
```

Does this mean that `app = require('express')();` actually returns a request handler function ? What is really going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It actually returns a function that takes `(request, response, next)` which is one of the middleware prototypes.  Essentially the express module exports a function called `createApplictaion` which returns a middleware handler.  [Here is the current source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L27) for express, you can freely browse it.

```
exports = module.exports = createApplication;

/**
 * Create an express application.
 *
 * @return {Function}
 * @api public
 */

function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
  app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
  app.init();
  return app;
}
```